# Send select value to JS function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the next menu in HTML:

```
<select name="p1">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Now, I want to send it to my JS function:

```
function myFunc(menuValue){
//do something
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get the value of the selected option `onchange` of option value right? You can try this way:-

http://jsfiddle.net/T8CKU/

```
<select name="p1" onchange="myfunc(this.value);">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

function myFunc(menuValue){
    alert(menuValue)
}
```

Here inside myFunc the context of `this would be the window. If you want to get the context inside the window as the dropdown itself you can use apply or call.

```
<select name="p1" onchange="myFunc.call(this);">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

function myFunc(){
    alert(this.value); //This will give the value again.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this :

Javascript :

```
var selectObj = document.querySelector("#selectID"),
    displayObj = document.querySelector(".display");
selectObj.onchange = function(evt){
    myFunc(this.value);
}

function myFunc(menuValue){
    displayObj.innerHTML = menuValue; 
}
```

HTML :

```
<select id = "selectID" name="p1">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
<div class='display'></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NeekGerd/4H5aq/

Comment: Why are you using querySelector to select by Id? Also `display` may as well be an `id` rather than a class.

Comment: Bad habit. I'm using jQuery too much I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The select element in HTML offers an `onchange` event that fires if you select a new value (new = an option that was not selected).

```
<select name="p1" onchange="myFunc(option);">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>

function myFunc(option) {
  // whatever you need to do
};
```